# Jquery html() is showing objects rather than the actual elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display the menu using `html()`as per my code below but it displays `'object object'` instead

```
var save = $('<a href="#" class="save">Save</a>');
var print = $('<a href="#" class="print">Print</a>');

$("#menu").html(save+' | '+print);
```

When I change the last line to

```
$("#menu").html(save);
```

it displays one link correctly. Could you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to declare your vars as objects. Just declare them as strings. If you want to declare them as object you cannot use any string concat in the `html()` function. For example:

`$("#menu").html(save+' | '+print);` will not work.
`$("#menu").html(save+print);` will work

Try:

```js
var save = '<a href="#" class="save">Save</a>';
var print = '<a href="#" class="print">Print</a>';
$("#menu").html(save + ' | ' +print);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"></div>
```